# how to optimize this eigen library code via openMP or by any other means

Tags: c++, optimization, openmp, eigen

I wanted to parallelize and optimize my code which uses eigen library but i am struck due to this situation

A part of code which take 2-3 secs.in one iterations is repeatedly runs many times due to a while loop, i am unable to use OpenMP on while loop but when using on part of code it shows no optimization.

code structure -

```
while(error>1e-6){
  //some code ...

  //part that i want to optimize
        #pragma omp for
        for(int i=0; i<18; i++)
          {
            XFG_e.coeffRef(IDOF(i)-1) += XFE(i);
            XFG_i.coeffRef(IDOF(i)-1) += XFI(i);
            for (int j=0;j<18;j++)
            {
                XKG.coeffRef(IDOF(i)-1,IDOF(j)-1) += XKT(i,j);
                XMG.coeffRef(IDOF(i)-1,IDOF(j)-1) += XME(i,j);
            }  
          }
```

}

please suggest ways to optimize this code... any better technique of using of openMP ,any library optimization ,other library alternatives etc..

Comment: Is there no `#pragma omp parallel` in your actual code? Without it the `#pragma omp for` wont do anything.

Comment: 1. You wrote ```pragma omp for```, did you mean ```pragma omp parallel for```? 2. That section of code looks way too small to parallelize efficiently. We can optimize the usage of Eigen, but efficient parallelization looks unlikely. 3. If you want to optimize your serial code, please include declarations for all your variables

Comment: What is `IDOF`? Is it a 1:1 mapping? Does it change between iterations? Can you move the shuffling outside your main loop? (I.e., `XKG_shuffled += XKT;` and outside the loop: `XKG(IDOF(i)-1, IDOF(j)-1) = XKG_shuffled(i,j);` -- even better if you could invert `IDOF`: `XKG(i,j) = XKG_shuffled(IDOF_inv(i), IDOF_inv(j));`, etc.

Comment: You didn't provide a full example (especially the types of the matrices are missing). By using a different [storage order](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStorageOrders.html) you may achieve better cache usage and thus better performance.

Comment: @chtz thanks for your response i got my mistake

Comment: @Quxflux sorry i was sort on explanation but i got my mistake
 thanks for your response

Comment: Just to clarify: There is a good chance that we can optimize that bit of code, maybe even by a factor of 2-4 but we need to see the type declarations at the very least. Knowing what changes between loops of the while loop would also help as well as which variables are used in the rest of the while loop

Comment: Are you sure this part of the code is the bottleneck (18x18 operations does not seem too much)?

Answer (score 0):

That bit of code is first of all tiny: 18-squared iterations. The barrier at the end of the parallel loop may very well be more expensive than the operations.

Next, that bit is written the wrong way for omp parallelization:

```
x(i+1) += y(i)
x(i-1) += y(i)
```

has no guarantees that the left hand sides are disjoint, so you will have parallel write conflicts. You first have to rewrite that as

```
x(i) += y(i-1) + y(i+1)
```

But first ask yourself, what does this code do? From the intended algorithm, would it be possible to have obviously-disjoint left hand sides under some rewrite?